# How to execute get after post in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm executing post from react and after that I have some calculations on my back end. How to execute get to show the result on my front end after post and calculation ?

Comment: What are you using to `post` from your react component ?

Comment: post can have a response, so you can add the response to the post request instead of a seperate get request.

Comment: axios or maybe I shouldn't ? axios
      .post('/api/OddsCalculator', newGame)
      .then(games => this.setState({games}, () => console.log(), games))
      .catch(err => this.setState({ errors: err.response.data }))
  }

Comment: @AneliaKostadinova — You're setting the state of your react app. How do you usually show data from the state? It's the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got your question, albeit vague. 
But,
1) You want to post a data to some route. The route maybe gives a `success` response or an `error` or maybe some different data, but it internally does some processing maybe adds some row to a db table.
2) You want to fetch the current state of the db table(I am assuming table, may be anything).

If this is the scenario, you can do what you are doing just add a get call in the chain.

```
axios.post('/api/OddsCalculator', newGame)
.then(games => {
    // this means you got your game
    this.setState({ games }, () => console.log(), games);
    //now add one get request as well
    return axios('/api/getSomeData');
})
.then((data)=>{
    //this data is from the GET call
    this.setState({ data })
})
.catch(err => this.setState({
    errors: err.response.data
}))
```

Hope this is a fair assumption, but feel free to edit the answer when you get your solution.

Refer Promise Chaining here: https://javascript.info/promise-chaining

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: if it worked feel free to mark the answer as accepted. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer

Answer (score -1):

You call it on the success of the previous method. You use nested calls. Please find below example where there should be two methods : yourPostMethod & yourGetMethod defined before you call them.

```
function handler () {
  return yourPostMethod()
    .then(yourGetMethod)
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result)
      return result
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have express tag in question, so I am assuming you're using that.

With express, `redirect` works beautifully. I use it all the time

Say:

```
app.post('/somePOSTpath', (req, res) => {
   // Do Some stuff
   res.redirect('/somepath');
})
```

This will direct your backend to `somepath` at the end.

Comment: The question is asking how to render an HTTP response using React … not how to make the HTTP response be a redirect.

Comment: @Quentin The question said "how to execute get to show results. . ." He did say "show results *on my front-end*" So, I assumed he set the state and stuff already. Then it becomes "how to execute get" Isn't this the same as asking how to make HTTP response? That was my reasoning

Comment: Even if you interpret it that way … a redirect doesn't send the data to the client.

Comment: @Quentin I never said that. The functions are missing in the question. When the question said "Did some calculations," I thought setState was already done. Then, he just wants to be able to go the get path.